# Compressed file does not appear after running zip command on dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, zip

Compressed file does not appear after running zip command on dockerfile. Follow Dorckerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:5-php7.0-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
  zip unzip

WORKDIR /var/www/html/application-folder

COPY app_files .

RUN zip -r wpfiles.zip wp-file/
```

Even though the compression process appears in the log, the file does not appear in container.

Comment: `/var/www/html` is declared as a volume in a parent's image Dockerfile (see `docker inspect wordpress:5-php7.0-fpm`). In short: any modification to that dir and its descendants performed by a `RUN` command inside your Dockerfile won't survive in the resulting image. If you really need the folder content and the corresponding zipfile inside that dir on the image, zip it on your host and pass it over with `COPY`. Else write the zip file outside of that volume.

Comment: And since you may ask: there is no way to "undeclare" that volume created in the parent image. Your only option in that case is to build your own base image from scratch or from a descendant image in the tree which does not have the volume.

Answer (score 0):

As the friend said above, the `/var/www/html` path is a reserved volume. If you want to manipulate files, just a new directory from root, example: `mkdir -p /temp/files`